# ¿Cómo pasar parámetros a través de <nuxt-link> en Nuxt2?

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-router, nuxt

**Problema:**

Tengo un `<nuxt-link>` en el que quiero poder pasar parámetros para que puedan ser accedidos en la página a la que redirige el enlace. Es un enlace dinámico con la siguiente estructura:

```html
<nuxt-link class="nuxtLinkDecoration" :to="`/${popular[0].attributes.titulo}`">
  <short-post class="ml-3 hoverMain" :img="'http://localhost:1337' + popular[0].attributes.media.data[0].attributes.url"
              :title="popular[0].attributes.titulo" :text="popular[0].attributes.cuerpo"></short-post>
</nuxt-link>
```

Donde **short-post** es un componente personalizado, y "popular" es un array de objetos, en el cual quiero pasar el primer elemento como parámetro.

Y la forma en que estoy intentando acceder a los parámetros es mediante $route.params en mi archivo _articles.vue. Sin embargo, "params" solo contiene una variable llamada "article" que almacena el valor de "popular[0].attributes.titulo" utilizado en el .

También he intentado el siguiente enfoque en el :

```html
<nuxt-link class="nuxtLinkDecoration" :to="{ name: `/${popular[0].attributes.titulo}`, params: { articleData: `${popular[0]}`}}">
  <short-post class="ml-3 hoverMain" :img="'http://localhost:1337' + popular[0].attributes.media.data[0].attributes.url"
              :title="popular[0].attributes.titulo" :text="popular[0].attributes.cuerpo"></short-post>
</nuxt-link>
```

Sin embargo, este enfoque rompió el enlace.

**Detalles adicionales:**

- Estoy utilizando Nuxt2 como framework de Vue.
- Podría considerar crear un componente y pasar props en lugar de crear una página y pasar parámetros, pero creo que el segundo enfoque es más adecuado para este caso, ya que literalmente estoy creando una página y no un componente reutilizable.

Muchas gracias por adelantado ^^

Answer (score -1):

Para usar parámetros en la ruta, puede seguir el mismo patrón que [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/), ya que Nuxt usa **Vue Router** bajo el capó.

seria asi:

```
<nuxt-link class="nuxtLinkDecoration" :to="{ path: '/', params: { articleData: popular[0].attributes.titulo }}">
  <short-post..."></short-post>
</nuxt-link>
```

De esta forma ya debería funcionar.

*Acerca de: "**Pecado sin embargo, este foco rompió el vínculo**".*
Probablemente la razón fue que estaba intentando enviar un objeto completo dentro del parámetro `` params: { articleData: `${popular[0]}`}} ``